# importing beautiful soup using python 3.6 on OS X

Tags: python, macos, beautifulsoup

please help!

I am using a macbook running OS X 10.10.5

I am trying to install and then import beautifulsoup using python 3.6 but am getting the following error:

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘beautiful soup’
```

This is what I have done:

installed python 3.6, this has installed in the applications folder, this is working fine with idle.
downloaded and installed beautifulsoup4, installed using: sudo python setup.py install. This has installed beautifulsoup4-4.5.3-py2.7.egg files into the Library/2.7/site-packages directory

My code is as follows:

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append("Macintosh HD/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages")
    import beautifulsoup4
```

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever checked the documentation of that package?

You import this package as below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: I have tried this but I get the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'. When I look in the directory structure there is no bs4 even though this does appear in the down load files. So do I have an issue with the install of beautiful soup? Many thanks.